# How to List all Internal Storage Folders in Android Q (API Level 29)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, file-manager

I am new in programming and want to make a file manager in android studio. I am facing problems in listing all device folders in API level 29 after `getExteralStorageDirectory` was deprecated.

Comment: Which problems exactly?

Comment: in making a uri of for playing a mp3 file..showing uri is null

Comment: So you do that all without any code?

Comment: i have tried this code but everytime it is showing uri is null......... mediaplayer = MediaPlayer()
                var uri: Uri = Uri.parse((getAppExternalFilesDir().toString() + namecopied))
                Toast.makeText(this, uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri)
                mediaplayer.prepare()
                mediaplayer.start()

Comment: Please put your code in your post.

Comment: Can you help me with listing all files from Download directory in android-Q? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593112/do-we-need-permission-to-get-all-files-that-is-self-created-by-the-app-after-the

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory), you will have to use [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE). This will provide you with the `URI` of selected `directory`, once you have the `URI` then you can access all the children of that `directory`. From docs

> #### Grant access to a directory's contents
>
> File management and media-creation apps typically manage groups of
> files in a directory hierarchy. To provide this capability in your
> app, use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent action, which allows the
> user to grant access to an entire directory tree. Your app can then
> access any file in the selected directory and any of its
> sub-directories.

There is also [ActionOpenDocumentTree](https://github.com/android/storage-samples/tree/228c8e0aa19586bfcf36318ddb191719537a45a4/ActionOpenDocumentTree) sample app on github which shows how to implement this feature.

Comment: As I linked in the answer [ActionOpenDocumentTree](https://github.com/android/storage-samples/tree/228c8e0aa19586bfcf36318ddb191719537a45a4/ActionOpenDocumentTree) is an example project on github. You can clone the repo on your local machine to understand the code better.

Comment: Can you help me with listing all files from Download directory in android-Q? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593112/do-we-need-permission-to-get-all-files-that-is-self-created-by-the-app-after-the